# Como sincronizar la lectura y escritura de memoria compartida (Windows y c++)

Tags: c++, windows

Quiero compartir información entre dos procesos. Lo ídea es que un proceso esté continuamente esperando a que se escriba algo en el archivo mapeado en memoria hasta que el otro proceso escriba algo en él y pueda leerlo.

He hecho el siguiente código de prueba pero presenta los siguientes problemas.

Problema 1: Tengo que lanzar primero el programa que escribe la memoria y necesito que sea al revés.

Problema 2: El proceso que lee la memoria solo obtiene el último dato escrito en la memoria.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para lanzar primero el proceso que lee los datos y que lea todos los datos que escribe el otro proceso?

PS: Sería estupendo no tener que usar blucles infinitos y cosas así para no tener un uso demasiado elevado del CPU.

Clase para manejar el archivo mapeado en memoria:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#ifndef SHAREDMEMORY_H
#define SHAREDMEMORY_H
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
class SharedMemory
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;

public:
    int mode;
    int buffSize;
    LPCTSTR fileName;
    LPCTSTR buffer;

public:
    SharedMemory
                    (
                        LPCTSTR pFileName    = "Local\\OutputData",
                        int pBuffSize       =   256,
                        int pMode           =   PAGE_READWRITE
                    )
    {
        fileName    = pFileName;
        mode        = pMode;
        buffSize    = pBuffSize;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SharedMemory()
    {
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Open()
    {
        hMapFile = CreateFileMapping
        (
            INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    /// use paging file
            NULL,                    /// default security
            mode,                    /// read/write access
            0,                       /// maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
            buffSize,                /// maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
            fileName                 /// name of mapping object
        );

       if (hMapFile == NULL)return false;
       return true;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Read()
    {
        buffer = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile
        (
            hMapFile,               /// handle to map object
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,    /// read/write permission
            0,
            0,
            buffSize
        );

       if (buffer == NULL)
       {
          CloseHandle(hMapFile);
          return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Write(void *pData, int pSize)
    {
        CopyMemory((PVOID)buffer, pData, pSize);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Close()
    {
        UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
};
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Proceso que escribe datos en la memoria:

```
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>    
#include "./../SharedMemory.h"
using namespace std;
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    cout << "Writer!" << endl;

    SharedMemory *sm = new SharedMemory();

    if(!sm->Open())
    {
        cout << "Could not create file mapping object! Errno="<<GetLastError()<< endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(!sm->Read())
    {
        cout << "Could not map view of file! Errno="<<GetLastError()<< endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    sm->Write( (void*)&i, sizeof(int) );

    system("pause");

    sm->Close();

    cout << "Done!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Proceso que lee datos de la memoria:

```
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>    
#include "./../SharedMemory.h"
using namespace std;
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    cout << "Reader" << endl;

    SharedMemory *sm = new SharedMemory();

    if(!sm->Open())
    {
        cout << "Could not create file mapping object! Errno="<<GetLastError()<< endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(!sm->Read())
        {
            cout << "Could not map view of file! Errno="<<GetLastError()<< endl;
            return -1;
        }

        int *val = (int*)sm->buffer;
        cout << "Data-->" << *val << endl;
    }


    system("pause");

    sm->Close();

    cout << "Done!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Ok, lo he conseguido... despúes de probar un montón de cosas lo único que funcionó fue un semaforo. Saludos!!